# Excel: find Max value of same cell in multiple workbooks

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have multiple workbooks which contain the same basic data received from different respondents. I am trying to find the Max value of a specific cell (`$C$17`) across all the workbooks. Ideally I need to avoid using code, as the organisation I'm working with is not keen on macros and my coding skills are limited so I will have difficulty maintaining it.

So far what I have done is:
- create a list of the filenames of the workbooks
- defined a name for that list (respondent_workbook_name_list)
- validated that I can access the individual workbooks via the use of the `INDIRECT` command (e.g. `=INDIRECT("'["&Parameters!C2&"]Equipment'!$C$17")`  )

I thought I would be able to feed this into the `MAX` command and use an array formula:

```
 {=MAX(INDIRECT("'["&respondent_workbook_name_list&"]Equipment'!$C$17"))}
```

but all it gives me is the value from the first workbook in the list.

I've searched multiple Excel help sites and StackOverflow, but no joy. It feels like I'm missing something obvious - can anyone help?

I'm on Excel365, by the way, on a Windows 10 laptop.

Thanks in anticipation.

EDIT:
To provide more context which may help people think more outside the narrow confines of what I've tried, the scenario is as follows. Eight suppliers have been asked to supply price lists for the same series of products and services. I provided them with a template spreadsheet to fill in which has multiple sheets. Each sheet lists the items they need to provide prices for in a specific category. What I want to be able to do is to provide Min, Max and Average values for each product or service cross all the suppliers, without having to combine all the workbooks. Hope this helps.

Comment: Are the workbooks all open?

Comment: Yes - I'm aware that it would throw an error if they weren't. There's no error - it returns a value, just not the correct value.

Comment: the function is given a list of values and is also returing a list of values - maximum for each entry in your workbook list. But I guess you are only entering it into single cell so you see only the first value. If you select the same number of cells as is in your list and then enter the formula you will see maximums for every entry

Comment: Use a range of cells on the master sheet with each cell having a link to the cell required on each sheet and avoid indirect...

Comment: I'm just looking for a single value output - the largest of the numbers from the individual sheets. I thought MAX should just return a single value.